# How can I inject dependency from a library in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library in which I defined a class let's say `MyClass` with `@Component` along with `@Value` but when I try to use this in my Spring Boot application and try to Autowire it, I get exception about Spring not being able to find this type and ask me to define a Bean. All other classes gets injected just fine that I have defined in the application it self.

How can I make the `MyClass` to be injected?

Comment: you are obviously doing something wrong but without seeing your `@Configuration` or @ComponentScan classes along with directory structure I can't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete information on about your library, how you are using it, we can't provide solution. Assuming everything on your library is correct, you can simply add `@ComponentScan` on the application that use your library.

Create a class as below and that should fix your problem.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"your library package"}) 
public class YourConfig {

}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, add more information on your question and I will update my answer accordingly.